# How do i put an element (element, priority) in PriorityQueue in Java?

Tags: java

I want for example:

```
PriotiyQueue<Node<T>> queue = new PriotiyQueue<Node<T>>();
queue.add(testNode, 4)
queue.add(testNode2, 1)
queue.add(testnode3, 6)
```

at the end I want a queue which looks like this but doesnt care about "how much the elements are worth"

```
queue = <(testNode2, 1), (testNode3, 4), (testNode3, 6)>
```

Comment: You need to use a `Comparator` that compares on this value. Given your use case, you would need to wrap your `testNode` in a wrapper that also takes a priority. The `Comparator` would then use that to sort them. You might be better of writing a custom implementation.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by `doesnt care about "how much the elements are worth"` ?

Comment: (Not related to this question, and I'll delete this comment, but you might want to have a look at [this question on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265620/372643), since it's about your question you've just deleted.)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Node class that has those attributes and use a Comparator that checks for priority.

Comment: or just have Node implement Comparable to have a natural sort.